# Disk Utility created phantom storage

Tags: disk-utility, external-disk

I have a 2TB external hard drive. I wanted to have a 1.8TB Encrypted APFS partition, and a 200GB FAT Partition (for use on Windows and Linux systems). I ran into errors trying to figure this out, and after going for a couple full erasures of the drive (thankfully it's pretty new), I now have:

- Three 2TB APFS Partitions
- A 200GB APFS Partition
- 1.8TB Free Space

This means my Mac believes that my 2TB Hard Drive has 8TB. Where did the phantom 6TB come from? Why does erasing the drive keep creating 2 additional phantom TB?

I've tried running First Aid, and even running a repair in the command line. But the computer thinks this drive is okay.

Comment: You need to: 1) run Disk Utility, enable View > Show All Devices, take a screenshot and post it here. 2) in Terminal runs the command `diskutil list` and add the output to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this is strange. I decided to do some additional troubleshooting.

I tried plugging the drive into a different Mac, and the phantom storage didn't show up there. Did the partitioning on that system. Plugged it back into my own Mac, and the phantom storage did show up. After quitting and reopening Disk Utility, all the phantom storage disappeared.

This was very weird. But this is yet another example where "did you try turning it off and on again" would have been a good question to ask myself.

Comment: It's probably because APFS volumes are dynamically sized (like sparse bundles) and share the available space with other volumes in the container. Regular partitions (often also called volumes) do not have this feature. More info: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/disk-utility/dskutl14027/mac When you add an APFS volume you have the option to set a reserve or quota size. Don't know why it changed after you quit and reopened DU though.